# Splash screen make http request and pass the response to another page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

What I am trying to do is when the splash screen is loading, a http request is made to the server to pull some information and pass the response to another page.

Below is the code I am working with.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { CacheService } from "ionic-cache/ionic-cache";
import { Apis } from './apis';

import { StayPage} from '../pages/stay/stay';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [Apis]
})

export class MyApp {
  rootPage = StayPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, cache: CacheService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public Apis: Apis ) {
    cache.setDefaultTTL(60 * 60);
      platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

      this.Apis.types().subscribe( response => {
        response.results;
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
        Splashscreen.hide();

      }, err => {
        this.Apis.error( err );
      });

    });
  }
}
```

When I run the above code, the splash screen is stuck on loading and doesn't move to another page.

Comment: Are you trying to show it on StayPage?

Comment: @ACES Yes. The splash screen will make the HTTP Request and send the response to `StayPage`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make HTTP request in constructor or ngOnInit of StayPage.

```
export class StayPage implements OnInit {
    ...

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
                public navParams: NavParams
                public http: Http) {  }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.http.get(apiUrl)
           .subscribe(
             responseSuccess => ...
             responseError => ...
        }
    }
}
```